# How to combine a variable number of WebService

Tags: java, web-services

I want to develop a Java client, which requests a variable number of webservices.
How can I make it the best, that the client knows which service provides which information for a particular topic. And the system should add easily new services.

Example:
Suppose we have different weatherforecast-services for every city.
Now I want the forecast for Chicago and the program should requests all services that can provide a forecast for chicago. How can I realize this? And how to deal with different types of responses(XML or int or...)?

Should I store the endpoints of the services in a xml-file and make a lookup, or so (UDDI)?
I'm stumped. because, I have no experience with such complex things.

thanks and regards

Comment: You should probably rewrite your title too

Comment: Well "to compine" is not an existing verb.

Comment: hehe, I mean combine. Can I change that?

Comment: Yes just click the `edit` link under your answer.

Comment: I edited it, you can accept it or edit it yourself

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends on how the services have been developed. It could be for example a ReST architecture, or services that requests a SOAP communication...

First thing to know is how the services are proposed to the client. If it's "SOAP services", then you're going to need the WSDL ([w3C doc](http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl)) that exposes all the services available, if it's ReST you need to know the URIs of the services.

And those are not the only two systems (as they are only xml-based), so you need to know how the website is exposing its services, and then understand the different ways to communicate with a service.

This [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/webservices/) may be good points to start learning about Web Services and Web Services architecture.

Comment: thanks for you reply, I know a little bit about wsdl and REST. I am confused how to manage and combine different services. For example, I want to use 10 SOAP-Services and have 10 WSDL files. How can I ensure which provides information about chicago? Try and Error? And how can I realize that in my code? I mean I can write 10 Methods for every Service :( regards

Answer (score 0):

there are several possibilitys for different webservices to provide information. some use [rss](/questions/tagged/rss) or other [xml](/questions/tagged/xml) based formats, others have their own API...

you could use something like an adaptor for each service wich operates on a generalized "driver" for the webservice's data exchange mechanism... so there would be a driver for rss feeds, and other common data exchange formats and one for each more specific API. those adaptors would use the different drivers in the same manner to extract the needed information, wich is to be displayd individually...

maybe its also possible to create an adaptor generator wich may be used by endusers to add their own webservices to the system...

Comment: Yes, thats sounds good. An Adapter for every kind of service. But how to check if the webservice provides the required information? I see the different response types, I think thats another problem to filter out the informations.

Comment: if you write the adaptor for let's say www.my-chicago-weather.org then you know it's a weather service for chicago by the time you code the adaptor... am i missunderstanding you?

Comment: Sorry I think we talk about Adaptors for every Protocol ( 1 for SOAP, 1 for REST(http), ...) and use this for all SOAP or REST Services

Comment: i thought more of 1 driver for each "protocol"... then you write an adaptor for your service in wich you specify the underlying driver to be used... so the driver is actually an abstraction for all the different data exchange formats... from the adaptor perspective they look all the same...

Comment: You mean an interface or abstract class which defines the methods which should be implemented in every special adaptor?

Comment: you could combine this with a public database for adaptors (and if needed specialized drivers for uncommon data exchange mechanisms)... then the database could sort the adaptors, so you can easily get what you want and skip the rest

Comment: i mean an interface with methods implemented by every driver...so every adaptor knows how to use a driver without knowing exactly how the driver performs the task... ok, i think we're chatting too much :-)

Comment: Ok that sounds like the right direction, but unhappily I need some sleep now :( thx

Comment: So I am back. I read a little bit and found some interesting things. I can use XSLT to transform the different dataformats into my own dataformat, what do you think? Back to the driver and adaptors. I understand you as follow: I implement an interface with e.g. a method getTemperatures(String city) and implement for every service a class which implements the interface?